# Showing that $\int_6^8 \frac{70}{(x-6)^3}dx$ diverges

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

Showing that $\int_6^8 \frac{70}{(x-6)^3}dx$ diverges

So, how would I explain that this integral diverges to people who have no experience in analysis?? This is a question from calc 2. What should I add to the explanation that "as the integral gets close to adding up the area's near x=6, the function gets infinitely big, so the integral is going to diverge to $\infty"$

Comment: Can't you just note $-14(x-6)^{-5}$ is an antiderivative? I'm not sure what you mean by "the function", but if you mean the integrand your argument doesn't work, e.g. consider $\int_6^8(x-6)^{-1/2}dx$.

Comment: May be using $\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon\to 0+}\int_{6+\epsilon}^8\frac{70}{(x-6)^3}\ dx=\infty$.

Comment: No experience using analysis? Can you simply ask how thoroughly you should answer the question, then? Because it’s hard to give a complete answer to this type of question without involving at least some analysis.

Comment: Unless you just began this topic, I would simply point out that it follows immediately (but show them how) from knowing the values of $p$ for which we have convergence/divergence of the standard test comparison types $\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{-p} dx$ and $\int_{0}^{1} x^{-p} dx.$ When I taught Calculus 2, these two types played a role somewhat like the $p$-series did/will-do when you're covering chapter on convergence/divergence of infinite series of real numbers. (Texts I used usually did improper integrals before infinite series, by the way.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x-6=y$ then

$$\int_6^8 \frac{70}{(x-6)^3}dx=70\int_0^2 \frac{1}{y^3}dy$$

and

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{y^3}dy \ge \int_0^1 \frac{1}{y}dy=\infty$$

since

$$\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_a^1 \frac{1}{y}dy=\lim_{a\to 0^+}[\log y]_a^1=\lim_{a\to 0^+} (- \log y)=\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

A more descriptive explanation could be that given $\int_6^7 \frac{1}{x-6}~dx$ diverges, and since $\frac{1}{(x-6)^3}>\frac{1}{x-6}$ for all $6<x<7$, we know that $\int_6^7\frac{1}{(x-6)^3}~dx$ must also diverge by comparison test. Because $\int_6^7\frac{1}{(x-6)^3}~dx$ diverges, we also know that $\int_6^7\frac{1}{(x-6)^3}~dx+\int_7^8 \frac{1}{(x-6)}^3$ must also diverge.

However, this relies on knowing that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}~dx$ diverges. I do not know of any non-analytical ways to prove this, but it is quite easy to prove/explain to another Calc 2 student:

$\lim_{a\to 0^+} \int_a^1 \frac{1}{x}~dx=\lim_{a\to 0^+} \ln(1)-\ln(a)$
This limit evaluates to $-\infty$, so the indefinite integral diverges.